# insert into mysql table using select query with additional php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here I need help for my PHP which is I need to insert into a MySQL table using select query. I did it, but my problem is it was running so slow. I tried to change my script into insert with select script, but I'm confused about additional PHP scripts.

This is my traditional PHP / MySQL script:

```
    q="SELECT s.name, nc.clss, s.mark, cs.study, s.note 
                        FROM try.`student` s
                        LEFT JOIN try.`new_class` nc ON ( nc.ClassID = s.ClassID )
                        LEFT JOIN try.`cat_study` cs ON ( cs.StudyID = s.StudyID )  $name_all = @mysql_query($q) or die ('Query: '.$q);         while ($name_all_save = mysql_fetch_array($name_all)){
                if($name_all_save[mark]!=0)         {           if($name_all_save[mark]>70)             {
                $note =  "Good";            }           else            {
                $note =  "Bad";             }                       }       else        {           $note = "totally bad";      }
                $sDate = date('d-m-Y');

                $sql = "insert into `stock product all list` (name, clss, mark, study, note, dates)
                            values ('$name_all_save[name]','$name_all_save[clss]', '$name_all_save[mark]', '$name_all_save[study]', '$note', '$sDate')";
                            mysql_query($sql, $db) or die('Error:'.mysql_error());  }`
```

I want to change it into a modern insert with select PHP / MySQL script, but I'm confused about where to put the additional PHP script.

```
    INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: Couple things.  1) please edit your question and format your code properly (indentation mainly!).  2) Syntax error on the definition of variable q, not terminated by `"` and `;`. 3) do NOT use mysql* functions anymore.  Move to PDO or mysqli.  Use prepared statements and bound variables.  Search for that on SO, you will find pages full of how to proceed.  mysql* functions are deprecated and dangerous!

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#mysql_extension for PDO and database related code, or https://phpdelusions.net/pdo.

Comment: "q=" I don't believe you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of altering the mysql query with php dynamically on the basis o condition, write different mysql queries on the basis of condition. That will be faster and less complecated for you. Thanks